# Fail to check the condition when the numbers very small and close to zero

Tags: r

I don't understand why R doesn't consider this number small and it pass this condition.

```
> d
            [,1]
x0 -7.774163e-13
x1  1.554874e-12

if(all(d==0)){
  statments 
} else {
  statments 
}
```

I do not know why are pass the first condition where d==0 as you can see the value for d are very small. Any suggestions? if I want d to be exactly zero and when d close to zero?
Thanks

Comment: Floating point arithmetic is not exact in R (and most other languages).  You may set a threshold for zero and use that.

Comment: https://cran.r-project.org/doc/FAQ/R-FAQ.html#Why-doesn_0027t-R-think-these-numbers-are-equal_003f